How to have both stacked and dodge bar in same plot in seaborn?
I am trying to have both stacked and dodge in same plot. In below example for each size I would like to have two set of stacked bar plot.
import seaborn.objects as so
    tips= sns.load_dataset("tips")
    p = (
        so.Plot(tips, x="size", y="total_bill", color="time", offset="smoker",)
        .add(so.Bar(), so.Agg(),so.Dodge())
        .scale(x=so.Nominal())
    )
    p


